# how to solve remove blurry font in jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am using this script code but it display the font blurry.How it solve the problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Doc is ready");

    $('#pdf').click(function() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'letter');
          var options = {
            pagesplit: true
        }; 

        pdf.addHTML($('body'), 0, 0, options, function(){
            pdf.save("Report10.pdf");
        });

    })
})

</script>
```

Comment: Change your question to markup formate

Comment: i am using that script but pdf in font is blurry how to solve  the that blurry font problem

Comment: that code in remove on pagesplit:true.that place put on  pagesplice: true this sentance

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem with jsPDF export for Highcharts and AngularJS. I have found one solution for this. I don't know why jsPDF behaves like this, but this solution Solved my problem. :)
 [You can check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9qAG.png)

Step 1) Add one empty div with id before your graph element div.

`<div id="tempStyleDiv"></div>`

Step 2) Write CSS selector for text element of your graph and assign property display:none. Here I have used inspect element of chrome browser to find CSS selector. You need to add following line of js code just before pdf.addHTML() function.

`$('#tempStyleDiv').append("<style>.highcharts-container>svg>g>text{display:none;}</style>");`

Step 3) After successfully export of pdf, now we need to remove display:none property. So just add following line after pdf.save(),

`setTimeout(function(){$('#tempStyleDiv').html("");},2000);`